# jquery autocomplete handle event when cursor moves up and down through dropdown list of results

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery-ui autocomplete, and I am tyring to handle the event that is fired each time the user moves up and down through the list of results by using the up and down keyboard arrow keys (not when using mouse).

Is that possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by handle focus event for this case and then I ignore default behaviour by returing false (sames as event.preventdefault()).